# Pesquisa no sql server 2014 com php

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Estou usando o Sql Server Express, tenho uma instancia instalada de forma individual em duas maquinas virtuais no servidor, umas das instancias instaladas é o **Sql Server 2008**, e a outra é o **Sql Server 2014**

Ao executar a mesma consulta em ambas as instancias tenho tempo de resposta diferentes, a **versão 2008** me retorna os dados sem problemas e de forma rápida já a **versão 2014** demora muito para retorna o resultado da pesquisa. Ambas as instancias tem as mesmas permissões no servidor.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar a fazer com que a **versão 2014** possa ter o mesmo desempenho da **versão 2008.** Estou usando `php` com o sql server.

Além disso notei que na **versão 2014** a instancia instalada está consumindo muita memória aproximadamente 85% de ram mesmo após o termino da consulta ele continua a consumir o mesmo valor.

Comment: Já tentou aumentar o CE no SqlServer 2014 para 120 ou para menos ? Faça o teste `ALTER DATABASE seuBanco SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL=110;
GO` testa 100, 110 ou 120.

Comment: Tente atualizar a versão do Driver que você está utilizando com o PHP e também a versão instalada na maquina. Ambas versões são express?

Comment: me repassaram que a versão 2008 é paga e a 2014 é express. Testei o mesmo programa no sql server 2014 express na minha maquina e a performance foi boa.

Comment: Primeiro certifique-se de que lado esta o problema. Faça um teste executando a consulta direto no Management Studio, se a resposta for rapida, então você já descarta problemas no sql server 2014, se continuar lento, você já descarta problemas relacionados ao php

Comment: Continuando... Pode ser muitas coisas, sugiro primeiro ir diminuindo as causas, quanto menos coisas tiver para analisar, mais rápido e fácil sera para encontrar o problema